# Recursive macro to parse match arms in Rust

Tags: macros, rust

I am trying to write a macro to expand a set of rules into code that perform token matching, but am unable to generate the proper code without causing macro expansion errors. I know that I can handle this other ways, but the key question here is not how to parse tokens but rather how to write a macro that can recursively expand a token tree with match arms.

The idea is that we want to read a token from the string and print it out. More code need to be added to turn it into something more useful, but this example serves to illustrate the situation:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
enum Digit {
    One,
    Two,
    Three,
    Ten,
    Eleven,
}

#[test]
fn test1(buf: &str) {
    let buf = "111";
    let token = parse!(buf, {
        '1' => Digit::One,
        '2' => Digit::Two,
        '3' => Digit::Three,
    });
    assert_eq!(token, Some(Digit::One));
}
```

The code we want to generate from this example is:

```
fn test1(buf: &str) {
    let token = {
        let mut chars = buf.chars().peekable();
        match chars.peek() {
            Some(&'1') => {
                chars.next().unwrap();
                Digit::One
            }
            Some(&'2') => {
                chars.next().unwrap();
                Digit::Two
            }
            Some(&'3') => {
                chars.next().unwrap();
                Digit::Three
            }
            Some(_) | None => None,
        }
    };
    assert_eq!(token, Some(Digit::One));
}
```

Ignore the fact that we do not read more tokens from the string and hence the `chars.next().unwrap()` is not very useful.  It will be useful later.

The macro for generating the above code is straightforward:

```
macro_rules! parse {
    ($e:expr, { $($p:pat => $t:expr),+ }) => {
        {
            let mut chars = $e.chars().peekable();
            match chars.peek() {
                $(Some(&$p) => {
                    chars.next().unwrap();
                    Some($t)
                },)+
                Some(_) | None => None
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Let us now expand this example to handle a little more advanced matching and allow it to read multiple characters with lookahead, so only if the characters match certain patterns. If not, the extraneous characters should not be read. We create a token tree with match arms in a similar way to the previous example, but here we want to support a recursive structure:

```
#[test]
fn test2() {
    let buf = "111";
    let token = parse!(buf, {
        '1' => {
            '0' => Digit::Ten,
            '1' => Digit::Eleven,
            _ => Digit::One,
        },
        '2' => Digit::Two,
        '3' => Digit::Three
    });
    assert_eq!(token, Some(Digit::Eleven));
}
```

The code we want to generate from this example is:

```
fn test2() {
    let buf = "111";
    let token = {
        let mut chars = buf.chars().peekable();
        match chars.peek() {
            Some(&'1') => {
                chars.next().unwrap();
                match chars.peek() {
                    Some(&'0') => {
                        chars.next().unwrap();
                        Some(Digit::Ten)
                    },
                    Some(&'1') => {
                        chars.next().unwrap();
                        Some(Digit::Eleven)
                    },
                    Some(_) | None => Some(Digit::One)
                }
            },
            Some(&'2') => {
                chars.next().unwrap();
                Some(Digit::Two)
            },
            Some(&'3') => {
                chars.next().unwrap();
                Some(Digit::Three)
            },
            Some(_) | None => None,
        }
    };
    assert_eq!(token, Some(Digit::Eleven));
}
```

Trying to write a macro to handle this could work roughly like this:

```
macro_rules! expand {
    ($t:tt) => {{
        chars.next().unwrap();
        inner!($t)
    }};
    ($e:expr) => {{
        chars.next().unwrap();
        Some($e)
    }};
}

macro_rules! inner {
    ($i:ident, { $($p:pat => ???),+ }) => {
        match $i.peek() {
            $( Some(&$p) => expand!($i, ???), )+
            Some(_) | None => None
        }
    };
}

macro_rules! parse {
    ($e:expr, $t:tt) => {
        {
            let mut chars = $e.chars().peekable();
            inner!(chars, $t)
        }
    };
}
```

However, I am unable to find something to replace the `???` in the `inner!`
macro with something that matches either an expression or a token tree.

- Something like `$e:expr` will not be able to match a token tree at this point.
- Something like `$t:tt` does not match the enum constant `Digit::Two`, which is a perfectly valid expression.
- Something like `$($rest:tt)*` as a generic matcher will fail since the Kleene-star closure is greedy and will try to match the following comma.
- A [recursive macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/macros.html#recursive-macros) matching the items one by one, e.g., a pattern along the lines `{ $p:pat => $t:expr, $($rest:tt)* }` will not be possible to expand inside the `match` statement in the `inner!` macro since that expect something that syntactically looks like `... => ...`, so this expansion gives an error claiming that it expect a `=>` after the macro:

  ```
  match $e.peek() {
       Some(&$p) => ...$t...,
       inner!($rest)
                     ^ Expect => here
  }
  ```

This looks like one of the [syntactic requirements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/macros.html#syntactic-requirements) mentioned in the book.

Changing the syntax of the matching part does not allow use of the `pat`
requirement since that need to be followed by a `=>` (according to [the macro chapter in the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/macros.html)).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you need to branch based on different matches inside repetitions like this, you need to do [incremental parsing](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/pat-incremental-tt-munchers.html).

So.

```
macro_rules! parse {
```

This is the entry point for the macro.  It sets up the outer-most layer, and feeds the input into a general parsing rule.  We pass down `chars` so the deeper layers can find it.

```
    ($buf:expr, {$($body:tt)*}) => {
        {
            let mut chars = $buf.chars().peekable();
            parse! { @parse chars, {}, $($body)* }
        }
    };
```

Termination rule: once we run out of input (modulo some commas), dump the accumulated match arm code fragments into a `match` expression, and append the final catch-all arm.

```
    (@parse $chars:expr, {$($arms:tt)*}, $(,)*) => {
        match $chars.peek() {
            $($arms)*
            _ => None
        }
    };
```

Alternately, if the catch-all arm is specified, use that.

```
    (@parse $chars:expr, {$($arms:tt)*}, _ => $e:expr $(,)*) => {
        match $chars.peek() {
            $($arms)*
            _ => Some($e)
        }
    };
```

This handles the recursion.  If we see a block, we advance `$chars` and parse the contents of the block with an empty code accumulator.  The result of all this is [appended to the current accumulator](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/pat-push-down-accumulation.html) (*i.e.* `$($arms)`).

```
    (@parse $chars:expr, {$($arms:tt)*}, $p:pat => { $($block:tt)* }, $($tail:tt)*) => {
        parse! {
            @parse
            $chars,
            {
                $($arms)*
                Some(&$p) => {
                    $chars.next().unwrap();
                    parse!(@parse $chars, {}, $($block)*)
                },
            },
            $($tail)*
        }
    };
```

The non-recursive case.

```
    (@parse $chars:expr, {$($arms:tt)*}, $p:pat => $e:expr, $($tail:tt)*) => {
        parse! {
            @parse
            $chars,
            {
                $($arms)*
                Some(&$p) => Some($e),
            },
            $($tail)*
        }
    };
}
```

And, for completeness, the rest of the test code.  Note that I had to change `test1`, as it wasn't a valid test.

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
enum Digit { One, Two, Three, Ten, Eleven }

#[test]
fn test1() {
    let buf = "111";
    let token = parse!(buf, {
        '1' => Digit::One,
        '2' => Digit::Two,
        '3' => Digit::Three,
    });
    assert_eq!(token, Some(Digit::One));
}

#[test]
fn test2() {
    let buf = "111";
    let token = parse!(buf, {
        '1' => {
            '0' => Digit::Ten,
            '1' => Digit::Eleven,
            _ => Digit::One,
        },
        '2' => Digit::Two,
        '3' => Digit::Three,
    });
    assert_eq!(token, Some(Digit::Eleven));
}
```

Comment: I tested your example and it works fine, but when I try to change it into using a separate macro `inner!` instead of adding the `@parse` tokens it fails with an error on the `=>`  after the 0. I checked the code and compared with yours, but I cannot see why it fails to handle the same constructions as input. Do you have any explanation to why?

Comment: @MatsKindahl: Well, I'm not psychic, so I don't know what you changed.  Obviously something important.  Also, I lightly recommend against using two macros; it's generally cleaner to keep all functionality for a macro in one place.

Comment: The arguments under [internal rules](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/pat-internal-rules.html) is perfectly valid, but I am wondering if there are some semantics of macro parsing that I am missing. If there is nothing special in that respect with adding the `@parse` I'll just ascribe it to some mistake I made.

Comment: @MatsKindahl: If you don't show me how you changed it, I cannot help you.  I cannot diagnose code I cannot see.

Comment: It was a stupid error and there are nothing in the semantics that require the use of the keyword, even though I agree on the reasons for doing it this way. Thanks for the help!